# SQL / Derby: Get last line in table. Bad performance with MAX function

Tags: sql, performance, max, derby

I need to know the last entry in a derby database with a few million entries. Using the `MAX()` function I get very poor performance. I also tried scrollable resultSets and jumping to the last entry but this is even worse.

Any easy simple performant way to get the last line without iterating over all entries?

SQL: `select max(IDDATALINE) from DATADOUBLE_2 where DATADOUBLE_2.DATATYPE = 19`
Table: `IDDATALINE [BIGINT] | DATATYPE[INTEGER] | DATA [DOUBLE]`

I dont know if any indexes are defined, i'm working with source code I took over. I'll see if I finde something, if I don't find anything where/how do I add an index?

Comment: Show us the query you use, the table definition and any index defined on the table.

Comment: I added the information to my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select max(IDDATALINE)
from DATADOUBLE_2
where DATADOUBLE_2.DATATYPE = 19;
```

You should be able to improve performance by creating an index.  I would recommend:

```
create index idx_DATADOUBLE2_DATATYPE_IDDATALINE on DATADOUBLE_2(DATATYPE, IDDATALINE)
```

Note this is a composite index using two columns in that particular order.

Comment: Can I add an index after the db is already created and filled with entries? Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Markus: Check the manual: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/rrefsqlj20937.html To improve your query I'd try an index on `(datatype, IDDATALINE desc)`

Comment: @Markus . . . Yes you can.  In fact, that is often recommended for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort descending and fetch the first row. Example:

```
select Something
from SomeTable
order by SomeField desc
fetch first 1 rows only
```